# scroll to bottom jquery not working properly

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have simple on code to see if bottom of page is reached alert.
but its not working as I wanted.

I scroll down and come again to top, then is showing alert box.
below is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            alert("bottom!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: your code is fine, there must be something interfering with this functionality, try to disable other JS scripts and try it again.

Comment: i don't have any other code in there...

Comment: I have tested your code and it's working fine when I hit the bottom an alert shows up immediately I am on chrome.

Comment: It wasn't working on mine, but the answer posted below by is working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came with this solution

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (document.body.scrollHeight ==  document.body.scrollTop +  window.innerHeight) {
       alert("bottom!");

 }
});
```